# Flattened list of child and parents to a tree view hierarchy

Tags: c#, json, flatten

I have a list of objects that looks like this:

```
  public class Folders
     {
         public string name { get; set; }
         public string description { get; set; }
         public string path { get; set; }
         public string id { get; set; }
         public AccessType accessType { get; set; }
     }
```

These objects were all parsed from a JSON that is quite an ugly one and I've managed to flatten the list down to this.

The problem that I have is that I need to create a Tree View using WPF, but now I have issues creating the hierarchy into the Tree.
The `path` property has the path to that certain folder.
Here is the JSON.

```
{
  "name": "DataRoot",
  "description": "Root data directory node",
  "path": "DataRoot",
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Second folder",
      "description": "Second folder",
      "path": "Second folder",
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Third Folder",
          "description": "Third Folder",
          "path": "Second folder/Third Folder",
          "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Fourth Folder",
              "description": "Fourth Folder",
              "path": "Second folder/Third Folder/Fourth Folder",
              "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003",
              "accessType": {
                "read": true,
                "write": true
              },
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Fifth Folder",
          "description": "Review Required",
          "path": "Second folder/Fifth Folder,
          "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Sixth Folder",
          "description": "Sixth Folder",
          "path": "Second folder/Sixth Folder",
          "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Seventh Folder",
              "description": "Seventh Folder",
              "path": "Second folder/Sixth Folder/Seventh Folder",
              "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't seem to develop an algorithm to make the hierarchy in the tree folder...
I was thinking to make good use of the `path` property, but I still can't find a good way to use it so that I can make the tree look as it should.
My list is flattened as I said, but now I don't know what will be a good algorithm to develop the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to create a Tree View using WPF

One has to enumerate the json nodes (`JsonElement` if using System.Text.Json)  and add them into the WPF `TreeView` by creating `TreeViewItems` based on what level of nodes one finds oneself at the time.

SO is not a place to *quickly* answer this question.

---

I have written a basic WPF JSON Treeview as a .Net Core WPF control that can be installed as a Nuget Package. Once installed see if it *flattens* the look as you want.

If not, look at my Github repository to see if an example for you to base your work off of.  (*Do you have an update to the code to suggest, please join the project and put in a PR*).

### Example Code

- [JSONTreeview Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JSONTreeView/) Check out the page on how to easily run it.
- [JSON-Framework/JSONTreeView GitHub source](https://github.com/CheetahChrome/JSON-Framework/tree/master/JSONTreeView)

  - Look at `TreeViewExtension.ProcessJson` to see how the tree and the package then work together to create a tree.
  - Look at `JsonExtensions.cs` to see how start to enumerate the tree to create items.